# I would like to use gsub in R to match all items which are not alphanumeric

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am searching raw twitter snippets using R but keep getting issues where there are non standard Alphanumeric chars such as the following `"Ì†ºÌøÑ"`.

I would like to take out all non `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789]` characters using `gsub`.

Can you use `gsub` to specify a replace for those items **NOT** in `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could simply negate you pattern with `[^ ...]`:

```
x <- "abcdeÌ†ºÌøÑfgh"
gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", x)
# [1] "abcdefgh"
```

Please note that the class `[:alnum:]` matches all your given special characters. That's why `gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "", x)` doesn't work.

Comment: x <- "abcdeÌ†ºÌøÑfgh"
gsub("^[A-Za-z0-9]", "", x) /////// this works better!

Comment: @user2236782: No this will only remove the first character of a line if it is part of `A-Za-z0-9` (`^` marks the beginning of a line; you want `[^...]` to exclude these characters from removing).